# What is a irancell hijacker?

Tags: google-account

Someone recently tried to sign in to Google Account - [example@gmail.com]

> We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a **hijacker**
>   trying to access your account.
>
> - Please review the details of the sign-in attempt:  date time UTC
>
> IP Address: List of All IP addresses in range - 5.121.191.0 -
>   5.121.191.255
>
> Location: Tehrān, Iran

The whois info for [the IP](http://myip.ms/info/whois/5.117.165.219). Is this real hijacker?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to tell, except that someone whose IP belongs in the range 5.121.191.0 - 5.121.191.255, owned by the ISP Irancell tried to access your account. Is it a real "hijacker"? Presumably yes. Is it guaranteed for sure that 'hijacker' is from Iran? That's hard to say because IP address spoofing is trivial.

I'd definitely ask you to change your password